# Rename multiple files, exclude pattern

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to rename multiple files using the command-line, removing a pattern from the filename while retaining the rest.

Original output:

```
$ ls
Versailles - Holy Grail (2011)
Versailles - Jubilee (2010)
Versailles - Noble (2008)
```

Desired output after command:

```
$ ls
Holy Grail (2011)
Jubilee (2010)
Noble (2008)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Bash

With pure Bash, removing everything up to the first `-`:

```
for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "${f#*- }"; done
```

If you want to remove everything up to the *last* `-`, use `##` instead of `#`.

To break it down:

- The `for` iterates over every file in the current directory (`*`), and calls `mv` on each file found.
- The `--` tells `mv` to stop parsing options and is a safeguard to prevent files starting with `-` from being interpreted as options (e.g. a file called `-i` would cause `mv` to prompt you before moving).
- The `${f#*- }` is [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) and removes the part you don't want from each filename.
- All variables are quoted to prevent filenames with spaces or globbing characters to break the command. Always double-quote your variables.

#### `rename`

With [`rename`](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) that's commonly found in Linux distributions, e.g. if you want to specify the artist:

```
rename 's/Versailles - //' *
```

Or if you want to remove everything up to the last `-`:

```
rename 's/.*- //' *
```

#### Zsh

In Zsh and [`zmv`](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv), which you need to load with `autoload -U zmv`:

```
zmv 'Versailles - (*)' '$1'
```

Comment: Thanks! I use Zsh and have `rename` installed, but I want to do this with bash. Could you break down the `for`-loop for me?

Comment: Great in-depth answer. Thanks again :)